# What's the reason for the discrepancy in the backstory involving Fetch and her brother?

Tags: infamous-second-son, infamous-first-light

In *Infamous First Light*, Fetch kills her brother, Brent, on a trip accidentally while she is under the effect of drugs that she gets injected with.

In *Infamous Second Son*, the story about Fetch is that she and her brother were addicted to drugs, and Fetch killed Brent on a trip because she thought he stole her some stuff.

My question is: Is there a reason for this little difference in the story, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you're asking a question, the full question should be un-spoilered.  We're not in the business of tapdancing around a question.  I would recommend rolling back the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Per the Infamous Wiki of [Brent Walker](http://infamous.wikia.com/wiki/Brent_Walker), there is some information in the Trivia section that explains the reason for the differences in the story

> His death in First Light differs from what Delsin saw in his vision when he took Abigail's power. In Second Son, it is stated that Abigail killed her brother after he hid her drugs from her. In First Light, Abigail accidentally killed him during a Drug Trip caused by Shane
> However, just before she kills him, she screams asking where her drugs were, which was out of context (except if she was referencing the time when Brent hid her drugs from her in an attempt to make her quit). It's possible that Delsin confused the drug hallucinations and her reality as one.